# Cuda Memory access error : CudaIllegalAddress , Image Processing(Stereo vision)

Tags: image-processing, cuda

```
I'm using cuda to deal with image proccessing. but my result is always get 'cudaErrorIllegalAddress : an illegal memory access was encountered'
```

What i did is below.

First, Load converted image(rgb to gray) to device, i use 'cudaMallocPitch' and 'cudaMemcpy2D'

```
unsigned char *dev_srcleft;
size_t dev_srcleftPitch
cudaMallocPitch((void**)&dev_srcleft, &dev_srcleftPitch, COLS * sizeof(int), ROWS));
cudaMemcpy2D(dev_srcleft, dev_srcleftPitch, host_srcConvertL.data, host_srcConvertL.step,
    COLS, ROWS, cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
```

And, Allocating 2D array for store result. the result value is describe as 27bit, so what i'm trying is using 'int' which is 4bytes=32bits, not only for ample size , atomic operation(atomicOr, atomicXor) is needed for performance.
and my device is not supports 64bit atomic operation.

```
int *dev_leftTrans;
cudaMallocPitch((void**)&dev_leftTrans, &dev_leftTransPitch, COLS * sizeof(int), ROWS);
cudaMemset2D(dev_leftTrans, dev_leftTransPitch, 0, COLS, ROWS);
```

Memory allocation and memcpy2D works great, and i check by

```
Mat temp_output(ROWS, COLS, 0);
cudaMemcpy2D(temp_output.data, temp_output.step, dev_srcleft, dev_srcleftPitch, COLS, ROWS, cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);
imshow("temp", temp_output);
```

Then, Do kernel code.

```
__global__ void TestKernel(unsigned char *src, size_t src_pitch, 
                                     int *dst, size_t dst_pitch,
                            unsigned int COLS, unsigned int ROWS)
{
    const unsigned int x = blockIdx.x * blockDim.x + threadIdx.x;
    const unsigned int y = blockIdx.y * blockDim.y + threadIdx.y;

    unsigned char src_val = src[x + y * src_pitch];
    dst[x + y * dst_pitch] = src_val;
}

dim3 dimblock(3, 3);
dim3 dimGrid(ceil((float)COLS / dimblock.x), ceil((float)ROWS /  dimblock.y));
TestKernel << <dimGrid, dimblock, dimblock.x * dimblock.y * sizeof(char) >> >
    (dev_srcleft, dev_srcleftPitch, dev_leftTrans, dev_leftTransPitch, COLS, ROWS);
```

Parameter COLS and ROWS is size of image.
I think the error occurs here : TestKerenl.

src_val, reading from global memory works good but when i'm trying to access dst, it blows up with cudaErrorIllegalAddress

I don't know what is wrong, and i sufferd for 4 days. please help me

below is my full code

```
#include <cuda.h>
#include <cuda_runtime.h>
#include <cuda_runtime_api.h>
#include <device_functions.h>
#include <cuda_device_runtime_api.h>
#include <device_launch_parameters.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <opencv2\opencv.hpp>
#include<string>



#define HANDLE_ERROR(err)(HandleError(err, __FILE__, __LINE__))
static void HandleError(cudaError_t err, const char*file, int line)
{
    if (err != cudaSuccess)
    {
        printf("%s in %s at line %d\n", cudaGetErrorString(err), file, line);
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
}
using namespace std;
using namespace cv;

string imagePath = "Ted";
string imagePathL = imagePath + "imL.png";
string imagePathR = imagePath + "imR.png";


__global__ void TestKernel(unsigned char*src, size_t src_pitch,
                       int *dst, size_t dst_pitch,
                       unsigned int COLS, unsigned int ROWS)
{
    const unsigned int x = blockIdx.x * blockDim.x + threadIdx.x;
    const unsigned int y = blockIdx.y * blockDim.y + threadIdx.y;
    if ((COLS< x) && (ROWS < y)) return;

    unsigned char src_val = src[x + y * src_pitch];
    dst[x + y * dst_pitch] = src_val;
}

int main(void)
{
    //Print_DeviceProperty();
    //Left Image Load
    Mat host_srcImgL = imread(imagePathL, CV_LOAD_IMAGE_UNCHANGED);
    if (host_srcImgL.empty()){ cout << "Left Image Load Fail!" << endl;     return; }
    Mat host_srcConvertL;
    cvtColor(host_srcImgL, host_srcConvertL, CV_BGR2GRAY);

    //Right Image Load
    Mat host_srcImgR = imread(imagePathR, CV_LOAD_IMAGE_UNCHANGED);
    if (host_srcImgL.empty()){ cout << "Right Image Load Fail!" << endl; return; }
    Mat host_srcConvertR;
    cvtColor(host_srcImgR, host_srcConvertR, CV_BGR2GRAY);

    //Create parameters
    unsigned int COLS = host_srcConvertL.cols;
    unsigned int ROWS = host_srcConvertR.rows;
    unsigned int SIZE = COLS * ROWS;
    imshow("Left source image", host_srcConvertL);
    imshow("Right source image", host_srcConvertR);

    unsigned char *dev_srcleft, *dev_srcright, *dev_disp;
    int *dev_leftTrans, *dev_rightTrans;
    size_t dev_srcleftPitch, dev_srcrightPitch, dev_dispPitch, dev_leftTransPitch, dev_rightTransPitch;
    cudaMallocPitch((void**)&dev_srcleft, &dev_srcleftPitch, COLS, ROWS);
    cudaMallocPitch((void**)&dev_srcright, &dev_srcrightPitch, COLS, ROWS);
    cudaMallocPitch((void**)&dev_disp, &dev_dispPitch, COLS, ROWS);
    cudaMallocPitch((void**)&dev_leftTrans, &dev_leftTransPitch, COLS * sizeof(int), ROWS);
    cudaMallocPitch((void**)&dev_rightTrans, &dev_rightTransPitch, COLS * sizeof(int), ROWS);

    cudaMemcpy2D(dev_srcleft, dev_srcleftPitch, host_srcConvertL.data, host_srcConvertL.step,
    COLS, ROWS, cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
    cudaMemcpy2D(dev_srcright, dev_srcrightPitch, host_srcConvertR.data, host_srcConvertR.step,
    COLS, ROWS, cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
    cudaMemset(dev_disp, 255, dev_dispPitch * ROWS);

    dim3 dimblock(3, 3);
    dim3 dimGrid(ceil((float)COLS / dimblock.x), ceil((float)ROWS / dimblock.y));




    cudaEvent_t start, stop;
    float elapsedtime;
    cudaEventCreate(&start);
    cudaEventCreate(&stop);
    cudaEventRecord(start, 0);

    TestKernel << <dimGrid, dimblock, dimblock.x * dimblock.y * sizeof(char) >> >
    (dev_srcleft, dev_srcleftPitch, dev_leftTrans, dev_leftTransPitch, COLS, ROWS);
    /*TestKernel << <dimGrid, dimblock, dimblock.x * dimblock.y * sizeof(char) >> >
    (dev_srcright, dev_srcrightPitch, dev_rightTrans, dev_rightTransPitch, COLS, ROWS);*/
    cudaThreadSynchronize();

    cudaError_t res = cudaGetLastError();
    if (res != cudaSuccess)
    printf("%s : %s\n", cudaGetErrorName(res), cudaGetErrorString(res));

    cudaEventRecord(stop, 0);
    cudaEventSynchronize(stop);
    cudaEventElapsedTime(&elapsedtime, start, stop);
    cudaEventDestroy(start);
    cudaEventDestroy(stop);
    cout << elapsedtime << "msec" << endl;


    Mat temp_output(ROWS, COLS, 0);
    cudaMemcpy2D((int*)temp_output.data, temp_output.step, dev_leftTrans, dev_leftTransPitch, COLS, ROWS, cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);
    imshow("temp", temp_output);
    waitKey(0);
    return 0;
}
```

And this is my environment vs2013, cuda v6.5 
Device' property's below

```
Major revision number:         3
Minor revision number:         0
 Name:                          GeForce GTX 760 (192-bit)
 Total global memory:           1610612736
 Total shared memory per block: 49152
 Total registers per block:     65536
 Warp size:                     32
 Maximum memory pitch:          2147483647
 Maximum threads per block:     1024
 Maximum dimension 0 of block:  1024
 Maximum dimension 1 of block:  1024
 Maximum dimension 2 of block:  64
 Maximum dimension 0 of grid:   2147483647
 Maximum dimension 1 of grid:   65535
 Maximum dimension 2 of grid:   65535
 Clock rate:                    888500
 Total constant memory:         65536
 Texture alignment:             512
 Concurrent copy and execution: Yes
 Number of multiprocessors:     6
 Kernel execution timeout:      Yes
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another problem in your code is `pitch` usage for `dst` array.
Pitch is always in bytes, so first you need to cast `dst` pointer to `char*`, calculate row offset and then cast it back to `int*`:

```
int* dst_row = (int*)(((char*)dst) + y * dst_pitch);
dst_row[x] = src_val;
```

Comment: Thanks jet47,it seems work.
But funny thing is when i try (int*)((char*)dst + y * dst_pitch + x)
it returns misaligned Address error.
Do i have to always keep that forms of pointer that you suggested?

Comment: You should add `y * dst_pitch` to `char*` pointer (since it is offset in bytes) and `x` to `int*` pointer (since it is offset in elements). Or use `(int*)((char*)dst + y * dst_pitch + x * sizeof(int))`.

Answer (score 2):

One problem is that your kernel doesn't do any thread-checking.

When you define a grid of blocks like this:

```
dim3 dimGrid(ceil((float)COLS / dimblock.x), ceil((float)ROWS /  dimblock.y));
```

you will often be launching *extra* blocks.  The reason is that if `COLS` or `ROW` is not evenly divisible by the block dimensions (3 in this case) then you will get extra blocks to cover the remainder in each case.

These extra blocks will have some threads that are doing useful work, and some that will access out-of-bounds.  To protect against this, it's customary to put a thread-check in your kernel to prevent out-of-bounds accesses:

```
const unsigned int x = blockIdx.x * blockDim.x + threadIdx.x;
const unsigned int y = blockIdx.y * blockDim.y + threadIdx.y;

if ((x < COLS) && (y < ROWS)) {  // add this
  unsigned char src_val = src[x + y * src_pitch];
  dst[x + y * dst_pitch] = src_val;
  }   // add this
```

This means that only the threads that have a valid (in-bounds) `x` and `y` will actually do any accesses.

As an aside, (3,3) may not be a particularly good choice of block dimensions for performance reasons.  It's usually a good idea to create block dimensions whose product is a multiple of 32, so (32,4) or (16,16) might be examples of better choices.

Comment: Thank you for your reply robert. As you comment, i add code that deal with exception threads(region of boundary). but still i get illegal address error. i tried other side threads condition like
                  if ((COLS< x) && (ROWS < y)) return;
result was same. illegal address

Comment: You should provide a complete code if you want additional help.  That is something that I can copy, paste, compile and run, without having to add anything or change anything.  What I've described here is certainly a problem, but maybe not the only problem.  You have a curious mix of `int` and `unsigned char` relating to your source data.  It's not possible to tell if this is an issue or not.